# Trying to install Windows 10 on separate partition using a windowsToGo type method

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-installation, windows-to-go

does anyone know of a way to install windows 10 on a separate partition , im running windows 11 but i have an extra partition and want to install windows 10 on it, the issue is that im running win11 on an external usb ssd. So i need a way to install windows without having to go through the setup, like a WindowsToGo type way, i tried Rufus and WinToUSB but both of those dont pick up on my extra partition

Comment: Windows To Go cannot be ran from an internal partition only bootable flash media or the external SSD. Why isn’t running Windows 10 from a VM an option? You should be able to just duplicate the steps you did to install Windows 11 to the same drive and simply select an unallocated partition on the drive.